# Select After Spawning Subprocess in Thread Causes Main Thread to Deadlock

Tags: python, multithreading, select, signals

I'm currently having a problem with threads running sub-processes. The program uses the main thread to handle signals from the OS, e.g. SIGINT, SIGTERM, etc. It also spins up other threads which run processes in the background. However if the main thread is sleeping at signal.pause(), and a background thread runs a sub-process and then selects on a file descriptor it will cause the main thread to immediately deadlock. Any attempts to send a catchable signal to the program won't trigger any of the respective handlers.

This problem only seems to occur only on OS X using the bundled version of python 2.7 or using 2.7 compiled from source. I have tested the problem on Ubuntu linux with python 2.7 and haven't been able to reproduce the problem. I have also tested this in python 3.5 on OS X haven't been able to reproduce the problem.

Here is a snippet which can be used to reproduce the behavior:

```
import threading
import os
import signal
import select


def run():
    ping_r = os.pipe()[0]
    os.system('touch /tmp/blah')
    select.select([ping_r], [], [])

t = threading.Thread(target=run)
t.start()
signal.pause()
```

Is there something that I'm un-aware of / forgetting to set in python causing this issue?